# Nets of Geodesic spheres

Tags: math, geometry, tessellation, geodesic-sphere

I would realize the papercraft of a geodesic sphere like [THIS](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/G%C3%A9ode_V_3_1_duale.gif) .

Is the dual of the one discussed in [THIS OTHER QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031875/math-for-a-geodesic-sphere) .

Where can I find the printable nets, or the **online** resources to create them?

In the other discussion I learned that there are 3 classes of possible tessellations.
One of these classes needs less pentagons to tessellate the sphere?

I don't exactly know how much faces I need, indicatively between 100 and 200.
Which chord factors I should consider?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

genna,

The link that I provided in the former discussion...

http://thomson.phy.syr.edu/thomsonapplet.php

...provides for **display** of a dual. Unfortunately, the java applet will only export a data set for the geodesic triangular tessellation; **not** the dual.

[image: Class III {1,3} dual]

The dual can be constructed from the triangular tessellation, by importing the vertex *(point)* data set *(from the java applet)* into a 3D-graphics program, and then following the rules of the definition of a dual. *(Each pent/hex face will use the triangular vertex point as the centerpoint of a circle, being equidistant from the sphere center and normal to the central vector. The intersections of these circles will produce the linear edges of the dual faces.)*

All tessellated duals, based on the icosahedron, will have the same number of pentagonal faces (12), regardless of how many hex faces are produced.

-Taff